# np_expand and np.concatenate on large dataset

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am performing some data transformation (expand dimension for each image, then concatenate them for training) on a relatively large dataset: 62,000 face images from the wiki dataset. However, using the code below, I have been loading the data for more than 6 hours now and it is still not complete... How could I improve the process of loading images here? The below code is from the book [Generative Adversarial Networks Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1789136679). The whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Generative-Adversarial-Networks-Projects/tree/master/Chapter03)

```
def load_images(data_dir, image_paths, image_shape):
images = None

for i, image_path in enumerate(image_paths):
    print()
    try:
        # Load image
        loaded_image = image.load_img(os.path.join(data_dir, image_path), target_size=image_shape)

        # Convert PIL image to numpy ndarray
        loaded_image = image.img_to_array(loaded_image)

        # Add another dimension (Add batch dimension)
        loaded_image = np.expand_dims(loaded_image, axis=0)

        # Concatenate all images into one tensor
        if images is None:
            images = loaded_image
        else:
            images = np.concatenate([images, loaded_image], axis=0)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", i, e)

return images
```

Comment: `concatenate` makes a whole new array, copying values from the inputs.  So for a large iteration like this, the copy gets bigger and bigger with each iteration.  Usually we recommend collecting the arrays in a list, and doing one `concatenate` at the end.  List append is much more efficient since it just adds reference in-place.  Or make a large recipient array, and copy the new arrays to it one by one.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great explanation. I will try to implement your suggestion